# Sort dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Im using Python 3,6 and I need to sort by value an multidimensional dictionary.

This is the dict:

```
{'Num_Subdir': 11,
 'Path': '/root/git/dir1',
 'RealSize': '236K',
 'Subdir': {'1234': {'Num_Subdir': 10,
                     'Path': '/root/git/dir1/1234',
                     'RealSize': '44K',
                     'Subdir': {'ola000': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                           'Path': '/root/git/dir1/1234/ola000',
                                           'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                           'Subdir': {}},
                                'ola00sd1': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                             'Path': '/root/git/dir1/1234/ola00sd1',
                                             'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                             'Subdir': {}},
                                'ola00sdf': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                             'Path': '/root/git/dir1/1234/ola00sdf',
                                             'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                             'Subdir': {}},
                                'ola1': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                         'Path': '/root/git/dir1/1234/ola1',
                                         'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                         'Subdir': {}},
                                'ola2': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                         'Path': '/root/git/dir1/1234/ola2',
                                         'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                         'Subdir': {}},
                                'ola5': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                         'Path': '/root/git/dir1/1234/ola5',
                                         'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                         'Subdir': {}},
                                'ola6': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                         'Path': '/root/git/dir1/1234/ola6',
                                         'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                         'Subdir': {}},
                                'ola7': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                         'Path': '/root/git/dir1/1234/ola7',
                                         'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                         'Subdir': {}},
                                'ola8': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                         'Path': '/root/git/dir1/1234/ola8',
                                         'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                         'Subdir': {}},
                                'ola9': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                         'Path': '/root/git/dir1/1234/ola9',
                                         'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                         'Subdir': {}}}},
            'cece': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                     'Path': '/root/git/dir1/cece',
                     'RealSize': '4,0K',
                     'Subdir': {}},
            'dir11': {'Num_Subdir': 7,
                      'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir11',
                      'RealSize': '32K',
                      'Subdir': {'ola1': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                          'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir11/ola1',
                                          'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                          'Subdir': {}},
                                 'ola2': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                          'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir11/ola2',
                                          'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                          'Subdir': {}},
                                 'ola3': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                          'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir11/ola3',
                                          'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                          'Subdir': {}},
                                 'ola5': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                          'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir11/ola5',
                                          'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                          'Subdir': {}},
                                 'ola6': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                          'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir11/ola6',
                                          'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                          'Subdir': {}},
                                 'ola7': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                          'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir11/ola7',
                                          'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                          'Subdir': {}},
                                 'ola9': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                          'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir11/ola9',
                                          'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                          'Subdir': {}}}},
            'dir13': {'Num_Subdir': 7,
                      'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir13',
                      'RealSize': '32K',
                      'Subdir': {'ola1': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                          'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir13/ola1',
                                          'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                          'Subdir': {}},
                                 'ola2': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                          'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir13/ola2',
                                          'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                          'Subdir': {}},
                                 'ola3': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                          'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir13/ola3',
                                          'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                          'Subdir': {}},
                                 'ola4': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                          'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir13/ola4',
                                          'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                          'Subdir': {}},
                                 'ola5': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                          'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir13/ola5',
                                          'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                          'Subdir': {}},
                                 'ola6': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                          'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir13/ola6',
                                          'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                          'Subdir': {}},
                                 'ola8': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                          'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir13/ola8',
                                          'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                          'Subdir': {}}}},
            'dir14': {'Num_Subdir': 11,
                      'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir14',
                      'RealSize': '48K',
                      'Subdir': {'as1': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                         'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir14/as1',
                                         'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                         'Subdir': {}},
                                 'as2': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                         'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir14/as2',
                                         'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                         'Subdir': {}},
                                 'as3': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                         'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir14/as3',
                                         'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                         'Subdir': {}},
                                 'as4': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                         'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir14/as4',
                                         'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                         'Subdir': {}},
                                 'as5': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                         'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir14/as5',
                                         'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                         'Subdir': {}},
                                 'as6': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                         'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir14/as6',
                                         'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                         'Subdir': {}},
                                 'as7': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                         'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir14/as7',
                                         'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                         'Subdir': {}},
                                 'as8': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                         'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir14/as8',
                                         'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                         'Subdir': {}},
                                 'as9': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                         'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir14/as9',
                                         'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                         'Subdir': {}},
                                 'as90': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                          'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir14/as90',
                                          'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                          'Subdir': {}},
                                 'asd': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                         'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir14/asd',
                                         'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                         'Subdir': {}}}},
            'dir15': {'Num_Subdir': 12,
                      'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir15',
                      'RealSize': '52K',
                      'Subdir': {'as2': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                         'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir15/as2',
                                         'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                         'Subdir': {}},
                                 'as4': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                         'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir15/as4',
                                         'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                         'Subdir': {}},
                                 'as5': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                         'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir15/as5',
                                         'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                         'Subdir': {}},
                                 'as6': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                         'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir15/as6',
                                         'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                         'Subdir': {}},
                                 'as8': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                         'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir15/as8',
                                         'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                         'Subdir': {}},
                                 'asd': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                         'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir15/asd',
                                         'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                         'Subdir': {}},
                                 'qqwa': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                          'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir15/qqwa',
                                          'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                          'Subdir': {}},
                                 'qqwd': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                          'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir15/qqwd',
                                          'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                          'Subdir': {}},
                                 'qqwe': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                          'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir15/qqwe',
                                          'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                          'Subdir': {}},
                                 'qqwg': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                          'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir15/qqwg',
                                          'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                          'Subdir': {}},
                                 'qqwjj': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                           'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir15/qqwjj',
                                           'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                           'Subdir': {}},
                                 'qqws': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                                          'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir15/qqws',
                                          'RealSize': '4,0K',
                                          'Subdir': {}}}},
            'dir16': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                      'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir16',
                      'RealSize': '4,0K',
                      'Subdir': {}},
            'dir17': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                      'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir17',
                      'RealSize': '4,0K',
                      'Subdir': {}},
            'dir18': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                      'Path': '/root/git/dir1/dir18',
                      'RealSize': '4,0K',
                      'Subdir': {}},
            'jaja': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                     'Path': '/root/git/dir1/jaja',
                     'RealSize': '4,0K',
                     'Subdir': {}},
            'ola1': {'Num_Subdir': 0,
                     'Path': '/root/git/dir1/ola1',
                     'RealSize': '4,0K',
                     'Subdir': {}}}}
```

The expected results are that the output will be sorted bye `Num_Subdir` value, and show the same dict but with this order.
I get the dict by a function and i redirect the output of this function to var 'Dirs', so dirs is the dictionary.

I've tried to use `sorted` function but all the time I receive this error:

```
orden = sorted(['dirs'], key = lambda x: x['Num_Subdir'])
```

Error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

**EDIT**

Im simplify my Dict getting only that i will use in the future:

```
{'1234': {'/root/git/dir1/1234': 10},
 'cece': {'/root/git/dir1/cece': 0},
 'dir11': {'/root/git/dir1/dir11': 7},
 'dir13': {'/root/git/dir1/dir13': 7},
 'dir14': {'/root/git/dir1/dir14': 11},
 'dir15': {'/root/git/dir1/dir15': 12},
 'dir16': {'/root/git/dir1/dir16': 0},
 'dir17': {'/root/git/dir1/dir17': 0},
 'dir18': {'/root/git/dir1/dir18': 0},
 'jaja': {'/root/git/dir1/jaja': 0},
 'ola1': {'/root/git/dir1/ola1': 0}}
```

How can i sort now by the value of the directories?

EDIT2:

I got it with this: sorted(dicta.items(), key=lambda x: [int(x) for x in x[1].values()], reverse = True)

Thanks all

Comment: ``orden = sorted(['dirs'], key = lambda x: x['Num_Subdir']) ``You are sorting the string 'dirs' try using it on the data you have.

Comment: The 1st argument to `sorted` should be an array of subdirectories, not just `['dirs']`

Comment: Just note, that a python `dict` has no order whatsoever. A sorted dict (in `collections`) has.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I just edit my post. Dirs is the name of the dict. I get my dict by a funcion and i was assigned the otuput to a var (I dont now if this is correct): dirs = PathToDict(path)

Comment: @Dschoni: that's wrong; as of [Python 3.7, dicts guarantee insertion order, as a language feature](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html)

Comment: This question is problematic, it's morphed from the original asking about multidimensional dicts, so that part should be deleted, or at least reduced to a footnote and the actual question posted at the start. Anyway sorting (flat) dicts is a duplicate and should be closed as dupe.

Comment: @smci OP is using 3.6, so my comment is relevant.

Comment: @Dschoni: sorry, no. [Python 3.6 dicts guarantee insertion order, from the cPython reimplementation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation). If you're trying to say "Python dicts do not automatically impose (alphabetical, or any other) ordering on their keys", then that's correct. But the blanket claim "a python dict has no order whatsoever" is incorrect since 2016. It has whatever order you create it with.

Comment: @smci Maybe it's nitpicking but from that exact page: "The order-preserving aspect of this new implementation is considered an implementation detail and should not be relied upon [...]", however you told me something I didn't know and that's awesome (I always wanted to have insertion-order preservation... I should read the release notes ;)). So thanks.

Comment: @Dschoni Yes, in 3.6 it's an implementation detail, but since in 3.7 & onwards it's now guaranteed, the fact that it's just an implementation detail in 3.6 is largely irrelevant. Unless someone compiles their own version of 3.6 that doesn't implement the ordering. ;)

Comment: @Dschoni: that was only true for 3.6, like I told you last week [**3.7 promoted dict ordering to a feature guaranteed by the language**](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html). So what you wrote was out of date. A lot of users are not aware of the 3.7 change, let's not spread stale information with the now-obsolete *"a python dict has no order whatsoever"*. Also as far as 3.6 goes, like I told you **the cPython implementation of 3.6 implemented dict ordering**; just not pypi (or other implementations).

Comment: I already Ninja-edited my last comment. I got it now and am happy to have learned something new ;)

Answer (score 1):

If simplify your dict more to:

```
dirs = {
 '/root/git/dir1/1234': 10,
 '/root/git/dir1/cece': 0,
 '/root/git/dir1/dir11': 7,
 '/root/git/dir1/dir13': 7,
 '/root/git/dir1/dir14': 11,
 '/root/git/dir1/dir15': 12,
 '/root/git/dir1/dir16': 0,
 '/root/git/dir1/dir17': 0,
 '/root/git/dir1/dir18': 0,
 '/root/git/dir1/jaja': 0,
 '/root/git/dir1/ola1': 0}
```

Then you can print it sorted by number:

```
print('{' + ',\n'.join(
    '\'{}\': {}'.format(x, y) for x, y in sorted(
    dirs.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])) + '}')
```

Output:

```
{'/root/git/dir1/ola1': 0,
'/root/git/dir1/cece': 0,
'/root/git/dir1/dir18': 0,
'/root/git/dir1/dir17': 0,
'/root/git/dir1/jaja': 0,
'/root/git/dir1/dir16': 0,
'/root/git/dir1/dir11': 7,
'/root/git/dir1/dir13': 7,
'/root/git/dir1/1234': 10,
'/root/git/dir1/dir14': 11,
'/root/git/dir1/dir15': 12}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much, this is my objetive, but i cant to simplify my dictionary with this results..

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps...

Try OrderedDict which is very useful one,

```
>>>from collections import OrderedDict
>>>final_response1 = OrderedDict(sorted(dirs['Subdir']['1234']['Subdir'].items(),key=lambda t: t[0]))
#In the above these were the reference that you have stored **"dirs['Subdir']['1234']['Subdir'].items()"**
```

Now you will get sorted items.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i need to order all the dictionary, not only '1234'.. How can i order all?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the data structure you're using!

Dictionaries in python by default have no feature called sort. So, you need to think for an alternative.

One of the way to solve this problem, is to use list of tuple.

**Why list of tuple?**

A list of tuple can be easily converted to dict whenever necessary. For example,

```
>>> list_of_tuples = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
>>> a_dict = dict(list_of_tuples)
>>> a_dict
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
```

Now since your data is in dict format, you need to convert it into list of tuples which can be done using dict.items() method. Here's how

```
>>> a_dict.items()
dict_items([('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')])
>>> list(a_dict.items())
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
```

The result is exactly same as `list_of_tuples`. And remember, a key of a dict type object should always be an immutable data type.

**Now, coming back to your problem,**

> I've tried to use sorted function but all the time I receive this error:
>   `orden = sorted(['dirs'], key = lambda x: x['Num_Subdir'])`
>   Error:
>   `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

The value you're getting in x is a string not a dict type object. Hence, the `TypeError`.

> Getting your edit result:

```
data_dict = {k: {v['Path']: v['Num_Subdir']} for k, v in d['Subdir'].items()}
```

> Changing to proposed data structure

```
data = [(k, (v['Path'], v['Num_Subdir'])) for k, v in d['Subdir'].items()]
```

> Sorting it by path

```
data.sort(key=lambda item: item[1][0], reverse=False)
```

> Sorting it by Num_Subdir

```
data.sort(key=lambda item: item[1][1], reverse=False)
```

> Sorting it by Subdir name

```
data.sort(key=lambda item: item[0], reverse=False)  # reverse=True for descending order
```